# Not able to updating dynamic list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can someone help me, what should I do to refresh the drop down list that appears on Remove Locations page.  It is populated from `localstorage.city`.

Click on 'Open Panel' then click on Remove Locations. Here you will see a list of cities that I added by clicking on Add Locations button.

Delete some locations and then click on Remove locations button. You will notice that previously deleted locations still exists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- came from cordova -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" data-semver="2.1.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
<script>
 var SectedCityCode, URL, prov;
 $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/cities.js"></script> -->
<script>
    $(document).on("pagecreate", function() {

            // Save settings

            $( "#myPanel" ).panel({
              beforeopen: function( event, ui ) {}
            });

            $( "#myPanel" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {} );

            $("#myPanel").on("panelclose", function(event, ui) {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
              localStorage.adl = $("#checkbox-h-2a").is(":checked");
            }       

     });


         $('#btnDelCity').click(function() {
            var list = '';
            $("#delcity input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
                if (list == '')
                    list = $(this).val();
                else
                    list = list + ',' + $(this).val();
            });
            //localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.city = list;
            alert(localStorage.city);
            $.mobile.changePage("#home", { reloadPage: true });

            //$.mobile.navigate( "#home" );             
        });

        $('#btnRemoveCity').click(function() {

            $.mobile.changePage("#delLocations", { reloadPage: true });

            //$.mobile.navigate( "#home" );             
        });

    }); 
 </script>

 </head> 
 <body> 

 <!-- Start of first page -->
 div data-role="page" id="home">
 <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay">
    <!-- panel content goes here -->
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-h-2a">Auto Detect Location</label>
    <a href="#addLocations" class="ui-btn">Add Locations</a>
    <a href="#delLocations" id='btnRemoveCity' class="ui-btn">Remove Locations</a>
  </fieldset>   
</div><!-- /panel -->
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Open Panel</a>     
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>content will go here</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer --> 

</div><!-- end of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="addLocations" data-cache="false">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Add Locations</h1>
    <a href="#home" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form class="ui-filterable">
      <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
    </form>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" id="citynames">
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Locations Footer</h1>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#addLocations', function(){

      var cities = [{
        "code": "s0000768",
        "englishnames": "City 1"
      }, {
        "code": "s0000001",
        "englishnames": "City 2"
      }, {
        "code": "s0000404",
        "englishnames": "City 3"
      }];

        //bind cities to addLocations
        cities.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.englishnames.localeCompare(b.englishnames);
        });
        $.each(cities, function(i, obj) {
        $("#citynames").append("<li data-name='" + obj.englishnames + "'>" + obj.englishnames + "</li>");
        });
        /* delegation */
        //localStorage.clear();
        $("#citynames").on("click", "li", function() {
            if (localStorage.city == '')
                    localStorage.city = $(this).attr('data-name');
            else
                    localStorage.city = localStorage.city + ',' + $(this).attr('data-name');

            alert(localStorage.city);
        });

    }); 
</script>  
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="delLocations">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Remove Locations</h1>
    <a href="#home" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form id='delcity'>
    </form>


  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Locations Footer</h1>
  </div>
<script>
    //$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#delLocations', function(){

    $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#delLocations', function(){
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (!(localStorage.city == '')){
                    alert("about to create checkboxes");
                    var savedCities = localStorage.city;
                    alert(savedCities);
                    var arr = [];
                    arr.length = 0;
                    $("#delcity").trigger('reset');
                    $("#delcity").empty();
                    arr = savedCities.split(',');
                    $.each(arr, function(i, val){
                        $("#delcity").append("<label><input id='chk" + i + "' type='checkbox' value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</label>");
                    });
                    $("#delcity").append("<a href='#delLocations' id='btnDelCity' class='ui-btn'>Remove</a>");      
            }
        }
    });     
</script>  
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLsLo94r/13/

Joe

Comment: While the fiddle is a nice reference, please update your question and add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pagebeforecreate only runs once not each time you visit the page. For the delete page you can use pagebeforeshow to rebuild the list of cities each time you visit the page.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#delLocations', function() {
      $("#delcity").empty();
      if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (!(localStorage.city == '')) {
          var savedCities = localStorage.city;
          arr = savedCities.split(',');
          $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
            $("#delcity").append("<label><input id='chk" + i + "' type='checkbox' value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</label>");
          });
          $("#delcity").append("<a href='#delLocations' id='btnDelCity' class='ui-btn'>Remove</a>").enhanceWithin();
        }
      }
    });
```

Then use event delegation for the click event on the delete button as it is created dynamically:

```
  $(document).on("click", '#btnDelCity', function() {
    var list = '';
    $("#delcity input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
      if (list == '')
        list = $(this).val();
      else
        list = list + ',' + $(this).val();
    });
    localStorage.city = list;
    alert(localStorage.city);
    $.mobile.navigate( "#home" );
  });
```

Updated  **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dLsLo94r/20/)**